# How to apply class dynamically while doing custom pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I have a custom pagination on my screen. 
Now the issue is while i do my pagination

1. how do i apply the `active` `class` on moving forward and backward using pagination.
2. How do i apply `active` `class` when i click on the number.

I tried with javascript but it creates conflicts as there are many same values on the page. Also if i have to add extra `li` on click of next like 8 after 7, is it possible to do it in same function?

Please find my working code for pagination:

CSS:

```
/*Pagination CSS*/      

ul.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.pagination li {display: inline;}

ul.pagination li a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

ul.pagination li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

ul.pagination li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}

div.center {text-align: center;}

/*Pagination CSS Ends here*/
```

HTML:

```
<div class="center">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
    <li><a id="test1" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a id="test2" class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="test()">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function test() {
    alert($('#myForm').find("input[value='" + 1 + "']").attr('id'));
    document.getElementById("test2").className = "";
    document.getElementById("test1").className = "active";
    alert("test1");
}
```

Comment: Do you use Jquery?

Comment: If you are already using jQuery, why not do `$('#test1').addClass('active')`

Comment: @Tasos Yes. See first line inside alert

Comment: Well if you want to do it in JS alone here is a solution otherwise addClass() removeClass() in jquery simplifies things http://jaketrent.com/post/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/

Comment: @Tasos yes using jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I provide complete example, with preventing for arrows (prev, next) select

```js
$('ul.pagination').on('click', 'a', function() { // listen for click on pagination link
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
  
    var active_elm = $('ul.pagination a.active');
  
    if(this.id == 'next'){
      var _next = active_elm.parent().next().children('a');
      if($(_next).attr('id') == 'next') {
        
        // appending next button if reach end
        var num = parseInt($('a.active').text())+1;
        active_elm.removeClass('active');
        $('<li><a class="active" href="#">'+num+'</a></li>').insertBefore($('#next').parent());
        return; 
      }
      _next.addClass('active');   
      
      
      
      
    }
    else if(this.id == 'prev') {
      var _prev = active_elm.parent().prev().children('a');
      if($(_prev).attr('id') == 'prev') return false;
      _prev.addClass('active');   
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    active_elm.removeClass('active');
    
});
```

```css
ul.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.pagination li {display: inline;}

ul.pagination li a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

ul.pagination li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

ul.pagination li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}

div.center {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a id="prev">«</a></li>
    <li><a id="test1" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a id="test2" class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="next">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Check that if you click the current active element it is loosing the active class

Comment: Thank you.. Works good. but you have answered partially. If you can answer the complete question i will accept your answer.

Comment: @Shirish You want to add additional  page number button on click next if it already reach end?

Comment: Yes @Sojtin. Correct.

Comment: @Shirish like now?

Comment: Perfect Bro.. I will accept your answer. Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('ul.pagination li a').on('click', function () {
  var $this = $(this),
      $active = $('ul.pagination li a.active'),      
      $elem;

  if ($this.is($active)) {
    return;
  }

  switch ($this.attr('id')) {
    case 'prev':
      $elem = $active.parent().prev().children('a');
      if ($this.is($elem)) {
        return;
      }
      $elem.addClass('active');
      break;

    case 'next':
      $elem = $active.parent().next().children('a');
      if ($this.is($elem)) {
        return;
      }
      $elem.addClass('active');
      break;

    default: 
      $this.addClass('active');
      break;
  }

  $active.removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
/*Pagination CSS*/      

ul.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.pagination li {display: inline;}

ul.pagination li a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

ul.pagination li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

ul.pagination li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}

div.center {text-align: center;}

/*Pagination CSS Ends here*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="#" id="prev">«</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"id="next">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you . It works good. If you can kindly help me with the complete question i will accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

first of all give active class to the li and change css to apply the style on `a` tag below the li with class active

on the test function write this:

```
var index = $(".pagination > li.active").index();
$(".pagination > li.active").removeClass("active")
$(".pagination > li").eq(index-1).addClass("active")
```

and when you click on the special pagination item do this:

```
$(".pagination > li").on("click",function(){
      $(".pagination > li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest to have a parameter in `test` function that would notify next/previous. Then, you should search `current element` and then move in corresponding direction.

I have also added handling for selecting any page.

```js
$('.pagination li').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this)
  if ($this.data('action')) {
    $this.removeClass('active');
    if (index > 0) {
      $this.closest('li').next().find('a').addClass('active');
    } else {
      $this.closest('li').prev().find('a').addClass('active');
    }
  } else {
    $('.pagination li a').removeClass('active');
    $this.find('a').addClass('active')
  }
})
```

```css
ul.pagination {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.pagination li {
  display: inline;
}
ul.pagination li a {
  color: black;
  float: left;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
ul.pagination li a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}
ul.pagination li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
div.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="#" onclick='test(-1)'>«</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">7</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="test(1)">»</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```